# How do I automatically add people to channnel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot where a user will message the bot and the bot will add a person to the private channel. I need it to be hidden so can't just do this by assigning a role. Does anyone know how to add people to a channel to it in discord.py?

Comment: If you mean making it entering in the channel you can't. You can only move the user to the channel if it's already inside another channel with [`member.move_to(channel)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20move#discord.VoiceClient.move_to).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a role and name it private.
2. Create a channel and allow only users with the private role to send and read messages.
3. Time to code

```
import discord #pip install discord.py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.') # your prefix

@client.command() 
async def pvt(ctx): # !pvt will be ur command 
    if str(ctx.channel.type) == 'private': # if the command if given in dm
        private_role = ctx.guild.get_role(688683645707938885) # your private channel id
        await ctx.add_roles(private_role) # give them this role

client.run('your bot token') # your bot token here
```

Now, whenever a user will send !pvt in bots dm he/she can access private channel.....Thanks